# Display problem on third monitor

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have 3 monitors setup as shown on the first image.

[image]

On the third monitor (the one on the right), each time I turn on the PC it actually displays as on the second photo. Despite this, when I do a screenshot, the image is just like the first one.

[image]

To solve this I learn that opening the screen configuration and dragging down a little bit the third monitor, applying the changes and then dragging it back up it fix the problem.

I don't want to do this each time I use my computer, it's really annoying. Yes, I know it's a trivial problem, but I couldn't find anything like this anywhere else.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 if it helps.

Comment: I am having a similar problem on my setup. I have to turn on / off one of the duplicated monitors for Ubuntu to reset and figure out that I have 3 monitors